# How can i ensure a string has even quotations using automata?

Tags: state-machine, automata, finite-automata

How can i ensure a string has even quotations using automata?

For e.g.

```
This is a "valid" string which has two quotes.

This is "invalid" string " because it has three quotes.
```

Comment: `s -> odd quotes <-> even quotes`   s is the start of the string, switch states for every quote character, whichever state you are in at the end of the string gives you the answer.

Comment: I am looking for any standard approach for this - especially when there are multiple rules to match in addition to even quotes. All i could think of is duplicate all rules - one for odd, another for even.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following autumata:

[image: autumata]

[**Online Demo**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YqTFy0ZBg0hpl71J)

Answer (score 0):

We need to remember the parity (even vs odd) of the number of quotes we've seen so far. We'll do this using the current state. We'll accept if we end in a state corresponding to having seen an even number.

Initially, before processing any symbols, we have seen zero quotes. Zero is typically considered to be an even number, though some people may not mean to include it some of the time. We'll assume the usual meaning and accept strings with no quotes at all. This tells us that the initial state must be the one for even parity and must therefore be accepting. The other state represents odd parity and is not accepting.

The transitions will all be self-loops on the states, except that a quote symbol takes each state to the other of the two.